# In Inform 7, finding a thing by its name in a text that varies

Tags: reflection, inform7

Let's say I have a text that varied and that contains "lobby".

Now let's say I have a room a in my story called "lobby".

Is there a way to move a person (let's call her Laura) to the lobby based on that?

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
Let place be the room called "[the room name]".
```

Or, if `Anna` is a person:

```
Now Anna is in the room called "[the room name]".
```

Surely, there must be something like that. But I can't find it.

The long-term goal is to store names of people and places in text files and then restore them to references to things.

Answer (score 4):

I got an [answer on an interactive fiction forum](http://www.intfiction.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=16149&p=79774). I'm posting it here for documentation purposes:

Rooms and other objects are referenced internally by pointers rather than by name. If you really need to do that, you'd have to use a construction like this:

```
To decide which object is the (D - description of objects) referenced as (T - text):
    repeat with X running through D:
        if the printed name of X exactly matches T:
            decide on X;
    decide on nothing.
```